# Ngx-Bootstrap and Angular 9 ModuleWithProviders Error

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap, angular9, ngx-bootstrap-popover

I get the error below

```
ERROR in node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/popover/popover.module.d.ts:3:23 - error NG6005: 
PopoverModule.forRoot returns a ModuleWithProviders type without a generic type argument. 
Please add a generic type argument to the ModuleWithProviders type.
If this occurrence is in library code you don't control, please contact the library authors.
```

I just added Ngx-Bootstrap's Popover Module and imported `PopoverModule.forRoot()`. This seems to be Angular 9 incompatibility. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It's so petty how I solved this error.

I simply run `ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component popover`.

It says:

```
Skipping installation: Package already installed
Unknown option: '--component'
Unknown option: 'popover'
```

But when I served the project, it ran successfully anyway.

Answer (score 2):

you need add the following script into your package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  }
}
```

and then run `npm i`

see description [here](https://v9.angular.io/guide/ivy#speeding-up-ngcc-compilation)

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be fixed in latest version, which correctly works with Angular 9 - in 6.0.0.
Also, it supports Angular 10.

Answer (score 0):

Noe: This can also be resolved by specifying complete path

```
import { PopoverModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/popover';
```